# Which groups are the unitary group of a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, unitary-representations

Which groups are the unitary group of a $C^*$-algebra?

Does anyone know anything in this direction?

Comment: Excellent question! I've been wondering for a while, too, but there seems to be very little available. In finite dimension, U(n) is a Lie group and can be characterised as such. Otherwise, about the only literature that I know of is Kadison's "Infinite unitary groups"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer: for any given group $G$ there exists a C*-algebra $A$ whose unitary group contains $G$ as a subgroup.

Namely, take $A$ to be the (full) group C*-algebra $C^*(G)$ of $G$. This follows from the fact that the functor $U \colon \mathbf{Cstar} \to \mathbf{Grp}$ taking unitary groups is right adjoint to the functor $C^* \colon \mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Cstar}$ taking (full) group C*-algebras. Moreover, both functors are faithful and reflect isomorphisms. See [Nassopoulos](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijcms-password2008/21-24-2008/nassapoulosIJCMS21-24-2008.pdf).

Comment: You might also take the reduced C*-algebra. But in my view it says nothing about the OP (with due respect).

Comment: Well, the idea is that it shows that the class of groups that arises as unitary groups of a C*-algebra cannot be too restricted. Not a full answer, but the best I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

[Characterizing group $C^{\ast}$-algebras through their unitary groups: the Abelian case](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3687), J. Galindo and A.M. Rodenas (2007).

> We study to what extent group $C^{\ast}$-algebras are characterized by
>   their unitary groups. A complete characterization of which Abelian
>   group $C^{\ast}$-algebras have isomorphic unitary groups is obtained.

Comment: But this is a different question, isn't it?

Comment: @Joël --- the objection is that the OP is not asking about group $C^{\ast}$ algebra's?

Comment: No, the objection is that the OP is asking about the range of the map {C*-algebra} --> {topological groups} while your answer discusses the injectivity of that map.